# How to implement redirect response with an AJAX request in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

I have a simple scenario where I want to request a page. The request format is AJAX. If there is some error in the controller/action logic for that request, I want to redirect to an error page. The issue is that a redirect is not a JavaScript response type, so I am not sure whether it will work.

If there are no errors, then I want the page to be updated via the appropriate JavaScript response type.

What is best practice to achieve redirect responses given that the request format is AJAX?

Comment: can you specific the ajax library that you use? jquery or prototype-js etc

Comment: this will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: I suspect that, based on Stack Overflow's current on-topic rules, this is rather broad, and it may be put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery) enlightened me on what I think is the right way to do this, if your ajax response is ajax; at least, in the unobtrusive javascript paradigm.   In essense, the ajax call always returns a standard json package, which can be parsed for information payload or a redirect url.

Answer (score 3):

You can also put this in your `ApplicationController` to redirect properly for AJAX requests:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Allows redirecting for AJAX calls as well as normal calls
  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
    if request.xhr?
      render(:update) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
    else
      super(options, response_status)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: @iWasRobbed- I like this answer, but the OP specifies Rails 3, and so `render(:update)` won't work unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @Yarin Works just fine for Rails 3.  It's when you get into Rails 3.1+ that you need to replace `render(:update)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can use .ajaxError()

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
  location.href = '/error.html';
});
```

or assume you do a ajax post

```
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  // Do what it completed will do
})
.error(function() { 
  location.href = '/error.html';
})
```