# a Redirect_to from Destroy action always gets DELETE verb whatever :method I declare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have the following method in a controller named `tareas_controller`

```
def destroy
  @tarea = Tarea.find(params[:id])
  @tarea.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tareas_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
    format.js { redirect_to :controller => "clientes", :action =>"show", :id => @tarea.cliente, :format => :js, :method=>:get}
  end

end
```

The record gets deleted ok, after that I get the following code on the server:

> Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/clientes/12.js?method=get
>   Completed 302 Found in 174ms
>
> Started DELETE "/clientes/12.js?method=get" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-06 19:20:07 +0200 Processing by ClientesController#destroy as
>   JS Parameters: {"method"=>"get", "id"=>"12"} Cliente Load (0.0ms) 
>   SELECT "clientes".* FROM "clientes" WHERE "clientes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 
>   [["id", "12"]] SQL (2.0ms)  DELETE FROM "clientes" WHERE
>   "clientes"."id" = ?  [["id", 12]] Completed 406 Not Acceptable in
>   131ms

It seems to send the request with a DELETE verb to the new controller and I cant find a way to change that to a GET request to the new controller.

Can someone give me advise as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect\_to from "destroy" to "index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122006/redirect-to-from-destroy-to-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved though not in a nice way..

created the following route:

```
match 'mostrar_cliente/:id' => 'clientes#show', :via => :delete
```

then I rewrote the redirect as:

```
redirect_to "/mostrar_cliente/#{@tarea.cliente}", :format => :js
```

not a very clean solution, but working as intended :)

Comment: The  answer from @sequielo worked for me (passing `status: 303` to the `redirect_to`

Answer (score 45):

You should redirect with a status 303.

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting
>   after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using
>   the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior
>   such as a double DELETE. **To work around this you can return a `303 See Other` status code which will be followed using a GET request.**
>
> ```
>   redirect_to posts_url, status: :see_other
>   redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303
> ```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: this worked for in Rails 6.  _method: :get did not work for me.

Comment: this worked for me in Rails 7, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the log, that the parameter being passed in the query string is "method".

```
Parameters: {"method"=>"get", "id"=>"12"}
```

Rails is expecting a parameter called "_method" to determine the verb, so when you're doing the redirect you need to make sure that's happening explicitly:

```
redirect_to :controller => "clientes", :action =>"show", :id => @tarea.cliente, :format => :js, '_method' =>:get
```

Comment: Your answer makes total sense. I tried it but now I get the following answer from the server:

<pre><code>
Started DELETE "/clientes/14.js?_method=get" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-06 19:48:58 +0200
  Processing by ClientesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
  Cliente Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "clientes".* FROM "clientes" WHERE "clientes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "14"]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "clientes" WHERE "clientes"."id" = ?  [["id", 14]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 167ms
<code><pre>
weirdest of things is the headers I receive on my browser are:

Comment: Is that happening before the redirect? I'm having a little trouble putting together the whole picture of what should be happening here.

Comment: when I click on my delete link:
- first I get the "Started DELETE "/tareas/85.js" ok, which is fine. -- Right after that it calls the redirect_to which answers with "Started DELETE "/clientes/14.js?_method=get" ... Completed 406 Not Acceptable. Thanks a lot for your effort :)

Comment: Solved though not in a nice way..
created the following route:
match 'mostrar_cliente/:id' => 'clientes#show', :via => :delete
then I rewrote the redirect as:
redirect_to "/mostrar_cliente/#{@tarea.cliente}", :format => :js

not a very clean solution, but working as intended :)