# Index controller action is not executed and view not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my admin/tickets_controllers.rb, I have the following:

```
def index
  params[:direction] ||= "desc"
  params[:sort] ||= "requested_date_start"
  @tickets = Ticket.solr_search( include: [:customer_info, :customer, :executor, :notes] ){
    fulltext params[:query] if params[:query].present?
    with :status, (params[:status] || params[:filter]) if (params[:status] || params[:filter]).present?
    order_by( params[:sort], params[:direction] ) if params[:sort].present? && params[:direction].present?
    paginate :page => params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page]
  }.results
  render partial: 'tickets' if request.xhr?
end

def destroy
  @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
  existing_workflow_state = @ticket.workflow_state
  msg_success = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status has been changed from  #{existing_workflow_state} to cancelled"
  msg_already_cancelled = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} is already cancelled"
  msg_failure = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status is  #{@ticket.workflow_state}, it cannot be cancelled"
  if existing_workflow_state == 'cancelled'
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, alert: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} has already been cancelled"
  elsif !ticket_can_be_deleted(@ticket).nil?
    @ticket.workflow_state = 'cancelled'
    @ticket.save
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, notice: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status has been changed from  #{existing_workflow_state} to cancelled"
  else
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, alert: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status is  #{existing_workflow_state}, it cannot be cancelled"
  end
end

private
  def ticket_can_be_deleted(ticket)
    w = ticket.workflow_state
    if (w == 'closed') || (w == 'completed') || (w == 'submit_for_billing') || (w == 'needs_correction') || (w == 'cancelled')
      return nil
    else
      return true
    end
  end
```

The following is the route:

```
admin_tickets GET   /admin/tickets(.:format) admin/tickets#index
```

However, when I execute the Destroy action, nothing happens. The log file tells me:

```
Started DELETE "/admin/tickets/177685" for xx.xxx.xxx.x at 2018-09-06 16:58:53 +0000
Processing by Admin::TicketsController#destroy as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"177685"}
  ......
Redirected to http://test.myapp.com/admin/tickets
Completed 302 Found in 43.8ms (ActiveRecord: 30.9ms)
Started DELETE "/admin/tickets" for xx.xxx.xxxx.xx at 2018-09-06 16:58:54 +0000
Processing by ApplicationController#routing_error as */*
  Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"admin/tickets"}
  ....
Completed 404 Not Found in 14.0ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches admin/tickets):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:129:in `routing_error'
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'
```

But, if I hit the browser refresh button, immediately after, I get the tickets Index, with the following alert on top:

```
Ticket 177685 has already been cancelled
```

And the log file has in it:

```
Started GET "/admin/tickets" for xx.xxx.xxx.x at 2018-09-06 17:05:07 +0000
Processing by Admin::TicketsController#index as HTML
.....
  Rendered shared/_index_search_form.html.slim (0.8ms)
  Rendered admin/tickets/_ticket.html.slim (87.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_no_result.html.slim (0.0ms)
  Rendered admin/tickets/index.html.slim within layouts/application (95.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 140.2ms (Views: 101.5ms | ActiveRecord: 14.7ms | Solr: 4.0ms)
```

Any ideas why the admin/tickets Index view is not rendered, and needs a browser refresh for that to happen?

Comment: It looks like the browser is redirecting using a DELETE method instead of GET, that's why it fails. Not sure how to change that though, but there's a point to start debugging/searching.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the status when redirecting:
`redirect_to ..., status: 303`

Explanations in [a Redirect_to from Destroy action always gets DELETE verb whatever :method I declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472600/a-redirect-to-from-destroy-action-always-gets-delete-verb-whatever-method-i-dec)
 and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

The documentation says the following:

```
It is also possible to assign a flash message as part of the redirection. There are two special accessors for the commonly used flash names
+alert+ and +notice+ as well as a general purpose +flash+ bucket.

  redirect_to post_url(@post), alert: "Watch it, mister!"
  redirect_to post_url(@post), status: :found, notice: "Pay attention to the road"
  redirect_to post_url(@post), status: 301, flash: { updated_post_id: @post.id }
  redirect_to({ action: 'atom' }, alert: "Something serious happened")
```

So it is possible to specify both `status` and `notice` options. However, make sure to put them in the same order as the doc.

If that still fails for you, you can try using the `flash` option instead

Comment: This somewhat works. The redirect is done correctly now, but the Notice or Alert are not showing up with the Index view is rendered

Comment: Edited the answer ;)

Comment: Whether status is in the middle or the end, it does not seem to matter. The action is done correctly, but still no notice or alert

Comment: Can you try with `_path` instead of `_url`? This might be it. I'm out of ideas after that :O

Comment: please see my question. I am using _path and not _url, although I don't think it would make a difference.

Comment: Yup, my bad. I'd put a debugger in the index action, see if the notice `option` really disappeared or if it's a problem with the view. You can also try other forms for the redirect `redirect_to action: :index, status: 303, notice: ''`